# An easy way to get rid of *everything* generated by SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there an easy way to get rid of everything getting generated as a result of performing an SBT build? It turns out it creates target directories all over the place. Performing

```
sbt clean clean-cache clean-lib clean-plugins
```

... doesn't get rid of all.

Comment: I would like to see this too and have submitted a ticket: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/issues/detail?id=166

Comment: That issue tracker is no longer in use so I have resubmitted it here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/896

Answer (score 77):

On my system (Ubuntu Linux) with SBT 0.13.5 and some projects from the Coursera Functional Programming course I found the folders all totalled up to 2.1GB for 12 projects due to all the cache files and duplicated Scala downloads.

The current SBT commands that work and get *almost* everything cleaned is:

```
sbt clean clean-files
```

This removes the top level "target" and "lib_managed" folders (23MB down to 3.2MB in this case) but leaves some target folders under project:

```
./project/project/project/target
./project/project/target
./project/target
```

This is where the Linux find command (also posted by @jack-oconnor) is very helpful:

```
find . -name target -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This gets us back down to a mere 444KB for one of my own projects and the 2.1GB goes down to 5.0MB !

In windows you won't have as many useful command line options, e.g. no star wildcards in path names, but you can always try and force it with:

```
rmdir /s /q target project/target project/project/target
```

The best I can do on automatically finding is a DIR command:

```
dir /ad /s /b | find "target"
```

Comment: Is it necessary to have the `-f` flag when using the find command? Seems unnecessary and potentially unsafe.

Comment: This worked fine for me:
`find . -name target -type d -exec rm -r {} \;`

Comment: The "-f" portion of the 'rm' command should not be needed but on some systems it might be preferable to a long list of deletion confirmations.

Comment: You may want to use `-prune` option in `find` to avoid `No such file or directory` message in terminal. So it is `find . -name target -type d -prune -exec rm -r {} \;`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115863

Comment: @RudeDude where do you read about `sbt clean clean-files`, I can't find its documentation anywhere

Comment: @MinhThai This post is older and I was using SBT 0.13 but it still seems to be listed as an example in the 1.x docs online but not fully documented. When I checked on the command line just now I was able to run "sbt tasks" which lists all the different "commands" (called tasks) that you can run. The keyword "clean" is in this task list and says: "Deletes files produced by the build, such as generated sources, compiled classes, and task caches."

Comment: `sbt clean clean-files` not working with sbt v 1.1.1

Comment: @AlbertBikeev: maybe `sbt clean cleanFiles` works for you

Comment: sbt clean cleanFiles

Comment: to me `sbt cleanFiles` doesn't do anything

Answer (score 7):

Obviously this is very important for reproducible builds on an integration server such as Jenkins!

Ensure that all files, *including the ivy cache*, are stored within the integration server workspace, by supplying command line arguments such as this to sbt:

```
-Dsbt.global.base=project/.sbtboot -Dsbt.boot.directory=project/.boot -Dsbt.ivy.home=project/.ivy
```

and then click the Wipe Out Workspace button in Jenkins, or the equivalent in other integration servers. That should definitely do it!

Or if you are using a recent version of the sbt launcher script, you can simply add `-no-share` instead.

Comment: If you're already using Jenkins, then the [cleanup plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28728663/1080804) is a great alternative to making sure the workspace is cleared

Answer (score 5):

On Linux or similar, this is better than `find -name`, as it won't accidentally remove any directory named `target` that might exist in your source code:

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -regex \.(/project)*/target -exec rm -r {} +
```

If you're running this command within a shell, you'll need to quote the regular expression, for example, for bash:

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -regex '\.(/project)*/target' -exec rm -r {} +
```

With BSD find (e.g. on Mac OS X) the command will be:

```
find -E . -regex \.(/project)*/target -exec rm -r {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the very good suggested solutions, personally I include a slight variation as a gnu make task.

content of Makefile:

```
clean:
    find . -name target | xargs rm -fr
```

and then run:

```
make clean
```

I like using Makefiles as code as documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Pretty Clean](https://pretty-clean.github.io/) to clean the all of dev tools caches including SBT.

PrettyClean also cleans the SBT project's target folder.