# How do I force SBT plugins and plugins to be downloaded through Nexus?

Tags: scala, sbt

I think that by now I figured out how to force project dependencies to be downloaded through Nexus. (I did that by explicitly setting `externalResolvers` to a `Seq` with only one value:

```
override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
  externalResolvers := Seq("Nexus repository" at "http://.../nexus/content/groups/public/")
)
```

However, if I drop my Ivy cache, SBT still accesses a number of public repositories for getting the plugins. Ideally I would like that to go through Nexus as well, to make sure we are not dependent on those repositories to exist forever. (Which they don't.)

Any clues? (I'm on SBT 0.11.2)

Comment: I think it should work the same way. Just set your resolvers to a Seq in plugins.sbt.

Comment: I should have said I already tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: The repositories used by the launcher may be relevant. Did you try the solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9125419/241990) ?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, but I don't want to change this globally for my entire system. I have many projects that should *not* go through the Nexus repository. I just want one project to *always* go through this Nexus repository.

Comment: You could include an sbt script, jar, and properties file in your project.

Comment: I guess that could work, but I would prefer a solution in which we don't have to do that. But perhaps that's too much to ask for.

Answer (score 1):

sbt 0.12 added [Global repository setting](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.12.0#global-repository-setting) for this purpose.

> Define the repositories to use by putting a standalone `[repositories]` section (see the [Launcher Specification](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Launcher.html) page) in `~/.sbt/repositories` and pass `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true` to sbt. Only the repositories in that file will be used by the launcher for retrieving sbt and Scala and by sbt when retrieving project dependencies.