# How do I configure SBT with an internal Nexus repository?

Tags: sbt

I cannot access external hosts like repo1.maven.org via my current network. I have an internal Nexus repository though. How do I setup SBT to use that repository?

Example errors I get:

```
C:\Users\myusername>sbt sbt-version
Getting net.java.dev.jna jna 3.2.3 ...
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.

: problems summary ::
::: WARNINGS
   Host repo.typesafe.com not found. url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

   Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

   Host oss.sonatype.org not found. url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

           module not found: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3

   ==== local: tried

     \\NLON11P20106A\wbulaty1$\.ivy2\local\net.java.dev.jna\jna\3.2.3\ivys\ivy.xml

   ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

     http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

   ==== Maven Central: tried

     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

   ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried

     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

           ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

           :: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: not found

           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sbt 0.11: Using a corporate maven repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115405/sbt-0-11-using-a-corporate-maven-repository)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself but supposedly [Global repository setting](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.12.0#global-repository-setting) feature in current sbt 0.12 was created for that kind of situation:

> Define the repositories to use by putting a standalone `[repositories]` section (see the [Launcher Specification](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Launcher.html) page) in `~/.sbt/repositories` and pass `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true` to sbt. Only the repositories in that file will be used by the launcher for retrieving sbt and Scala and by sbt when retrieving project dependencies.